# How to read a text file then convert it to a list of tuples

Tags: python-2.7, file, tuples

I want to convert text file contains for example this:

```
Alex
Gheith
40
John
Stewart
33
```

into:

```
[('Alex','Gheith','40'),('John','Stewart','33')]
```

Current code:

```py
records =[]
f10 = open("PlayerRecords.txt","r")
for line in f10:
    line = line.strip()
    records.append(line)
t = ()
f10.close()
t = [(x,) for x in records]
print t
```

Current output:

```
[('Alex','Gheith',40),('John','Stewart',33)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like given below. i have taken str1 as multi-line string.

```
list1 = [line.strip() for line in str1.splitlines()]
l_iter = iter(list1)
mapped = zip(l_iter,l_iter,l_iter)
mapped = set(mapped)
print (mapped)
```